# What does this code really mean?

Tags: java, arrays

I made a **static method array searcher for int** for some pratise to clear myself for making algorithm. I made the static method:

```
public class ArraySearcher 

    public static int integerSearcher(int[] arr,int val){
        int match = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i]==val){
                match = i;
                break;
            }

        }
        return match;
    }
}
```

And in the main method I created an array of int and used my static method for finding a defined int in the new int array

```
int[] anIntArray = { 20, 30, 40, 60 };
int searchingAnArray = ArraySearcher.integerSearcher(anIntArray, 60);
if (searchingAnArray == -1){
    System.out.println("match not found");
} else {
    System.out.println("result found: "+ anIntArray[searchingAnArray]);
}
```

The question is that I did'n't understand the `System.out.println("result found: "+ anIntArray[searchingAnArray]);"` and what does this really means.

Comment: Which bit of it don't you understand? the `anIntArray[searchingAnArray]`? The string concatenation? The method call?

Comment: You found the index at what the number you are looking for is in the array. Then you print it by accessing to it.

Comment: The use of `break` and a local variable may well be a stylistic choice but I reckon just `return`ing the index would be clearer. Not really relevant to the question at hand though...

Comment: [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: not understading the: `anIntArray[searchingAnArray]`@JonSkeet. Sorry but I am a new member!

Answer (score 0):

> The question is that I did'n't understand the System.out.println("result found: "+ anIntArray[searchingAnArray]);" and what does this really means.

It means concatenate the String "result found: " with the `int` at position `searchingAnArray` in the array of int(s) `anIntArray`, then print that String followed by a newline.

You might iterate the array and print its contents like

```
for (int i = 0; i < anIntArray.length; i++) {
  System.out.println("anIntArray[" + i + "] = " + anIntArray[i]);
}
```

The output (with your provided array) -

```
anIntArray[0] = 20
anIntArray[1] = 30
anIntArray[2] = 40
anIntArray[3] = 60
```

Comment: It should be noted that the operator `+`, when given a String on the left side, will apply the appropriate `toString` method to the right side and then concatenate the two strings.  Ie, if the right side is an `int`, then `Integer.toString(theIntValue)` will be executed before concatenating the two Strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("result found: "+ anIntArray[searchingAnArray]);
```

Will look for `anIntArray` on `searchingAnArray` position. I.e. will look for the value of the array `anIntArray` at position `3` (3 comes from your method), then it will print:

```
result found: 60
```

If you mean what does `+` means, is, as @HotLicks said on his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274010/what-does-this-code-really-mean#comment39384196_25274126), a concatenation. It will convert `60` into a `String` and add it to the same `String` as `"result found: "`

Another example:

```
String name = "Chuck Norris";
System.out.println("Hello " + name);
```

It will print

```
Hello you're not Chuck Norris
```

nah, just joking, it will print:

```
Hello Chuck Norris
```

Another example:

```
int year = 2014, day = 12, month = 8; //This could be done with a date type but for demonstration purposes I'll do it like this.
System.out.println("Today is: " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
```

And will print:

```
Today is: 12/8/2014
```

As you can see it will concatenate a `String` and then an `int` and so on, then print it.

It could be seen as:

```
String stringToBePrinted = "Today is: " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
System.out.println(stringToBePrinted);
```

If you call concatenation inside `System.out.println(...)` it will do something like the above (in an implicit way), something like "creating a local variable" and then print it. (Not exactly that way but you can see it like that to understand it).

Hopefully that is what you're looking for, the best explained as I could.