# Java System.out.println syntax help for multiple variables

Tags: java

I'm new to java and  trying to print the values of multiple variables.But the quotes inside the  `System.out.println` confusing me.Can anybody explain the following syntax?

Why  `"+ b1.cc"` is outside the quotes ?

My code:

```
System.out.println("Bike data " + b1.brand + " " + b1.color + " " + b1.cc);
```

Comment: So it will print the value of the variable and not just literally b1.cc

Comment: " " will print a space in the screen

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't understand that "" is creating a space here that's why the quotes were confusing me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have:

```
String one = "1";
String two = "2";
String three = "3";

System.out.println("one: " + stringOne + " and two: " + stringTwo + " and also a three: " + stringThree);
```

Will print

```
one: 1 and two: 2 and also a three: 3
```

It is called concatenation. I.e. you "create a new String".

Look at [this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25274648/2180785) for mor information.

In you actual code `" "` will just add a white space between the values of your variables.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes create a String object for the JVM to use. The variables:

`b1.brand`

`b1.color`

`b1.cc`

will return a String object already so the quotes aren't necessary. If, for instance, `b1.color` was in quotes, it would print specifically b1.color and not what the variable holds.

Comment: I'm nitpicking but `b1.brand` and `b1.color` are not methods, they are just variables.

Comment: That's a good call, I wasn't paying enough attention. Edited for accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to learn about string concatenation in Java.  You can call a method to concatenate (join together) two strings, but you can also use the `+` operator.

The String class includes a method for concatenating two strings:

`string1.concat(string2)`;

This returns a new string that is string1 with string2 added to it at the end.

You can also use the concat() method with string literals, as in:

> "My name is ".concat("Rumplestiltskin");

Strings are more commonly concatenated with the + operator, as in

`"Hello," + " world" + "!"`

which results in

> "Hello, world!"

The + operator is widely used in print statements. For example:

```
String string1 = "saw I was ";
System.out.println("Dot " + string1 + "Tod");
```

which prints

> Dot saw I was Tod

Such a concatenation can be a mixture of any objects. For each object that is not a String, its toString() method is called to convert it to a String.

Comment: I have knowledge about string concatenation the only thing confusing me was the quotes ,because i didn't understand "" was just for the space!

Answer (score 1):

You have presented an example of String concatenation, equally valid would be building a String reference separately like,

```
String str = "Bike data " + b1.brand + " " + b1.color + " " + b1.cc;
System.out.println(str);
```

Java also supports formatted printing. Assuming those fields are all String(s) you could use

```
 System.out.printf("Bike data %s %s %s", b1.brand, b1.color, b1.cc);
```

or [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
 String str = String.format("Bike data %s %s %s", b1.brand, b1.color, b1.cc);
```